# php script to download files from a remote URL to the user's computer directly

Tags: php, html

I am looking to allow site users to easily download files (audio) that we have on a remote hosting service.

We have URLs that point to these files. The files are not held on the same site or server as the main site.

Currently we have links that point to these files, and some text that instructs the site user that they have to right click and select "save file as" in order to get these files downloaded to their local machine.

To make this a bit more user friendly, it would be much better if a site user could just simply click a link and have a script that would download the file.

Is this possible?

Having researched this, there are many online examples and SO questions about downloading files on the same server, or downloading URLs to your server.

This is not what we want to do here. We dont want to copy any of these files from the remote hosting service to the main web server.

This is for a site user to click a link and have the remote URL download the file directly to the users local machine, not the server.

Comment: what happens if you just left-click on your existing link?

Comment: what's the problem in the user to click a link on the remote url, and the hosting service simply send the right headers to start the download?

Comment: We have no control over the remote hosting server, only the main website. If you left click on the file, it will try to play in the user's browser. This is not what we need to happen. These links need to be "download" links for the user to download the file to their machine, not play the file.

Comment: If you have no control over the server, then there's little you can do. Without copying the files to your own server, the only solution is to use your server as a kind of proxy so that you can set the appropriate headers. Trouble is, PHP would have to retrieve the remote file each time. This would save you storage space, but obviously not bandwidth. Your user would also have to wait for your server to download the file. Not ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the following PHP:

```
$file_name = $_GET['filename'];
$file_url = 'http://path_to_audio_folder.com/' . $file_name;
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
readfile($file_url);
exit;
```

You could then call it from your script like: `download.php?filename=my_song.mp3` and it would be forced as a download to your visitor clicking on it.

Comment: This is a nice, simple solution and works well. Thank you!

Comment: Can we change the name of the file?

Comment: @VermaJr. Can you clarify? If you're meaning `filename=my_song.mp3` - it will take any MP3 filename providing it exists in your directory and is public.

Comment: @RyanA I have got my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to build a "proxy page". Your server download the file, and ***meanwhile*** it send the data to your end user. The simplest way to do so is to output the file in *chunks*:

```
$url = 'http://.....mp3';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($url));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked'); 
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

$stream = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, function($ch, $fd, $length) use ($stream) {
    return fwrite($stream, fread($fd, $length));
});

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Chunked `Content-Transfer-Encoding` allows the client to begin transmitting the file before the `Content-Length` field is known. With this the user doesn't need to wait the server to download entirely the file before starting himself the download.

Comment: sorry can you help me:
I need something that downloads file and sends it to the user and deletes the downloaded stream from the server. because I have limited file space in my server directory